# Owl Carousel Options not being read

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have a working demo [here](http://ankitdesigns.com/demo/gem/).

I have owl carousel added to the bottom of the page. I'm using this javascript to output the options for the carousel:

```
$('#owl-partners').owlCarousel({
        margin: 20,
        dots: false,
        nav: false,
        navText: [],
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 6
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I am not sure why none of my options are working, like I don't want the dot nav t o appear and I want the carousel to autoplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is using version 1 of owlCarousel, so to hide the dots, you need `pagination: false` and for autoplay it has a capital P `autoPlay: true` - This is however untested.

```
$('#owl-clients').owlCarousel({
        margin: 20,
        pagination: false,
        nav: false,
        navText: [],
        loop: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 6
            }
        }
    });

});
```